# Set keyboard shortcuts to move to the next space to wrap around?

Tags: shortcut, spaces, mission-control

I currently have 4 different spaces open on my Mac. If I hit <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> three times (my shortcut for moving right a Space), I'll end up in the last Space. If I hit it again, nothing happens.

Is there a way to make it so that going right from the rightmost space wraps back to the leftmost space?

I want it to behave more like the application switcher when I hit <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: I pin a couple apps to my first space and command tab to them to save the three presses to get from space 4 to 1 quickly. I kind of like that I can’t go past the end, but I understand you might really prefer a loop instead of an end.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to what you are trying to do, I use an app called [Which space](https://github.com/gechr/WhichSpace/releases) that puts the space number in the menu bar.  This enables you to always know which space you are in. Knowing this you can use control # to change to space number #.

Comment: You do not necessarily need a third-party app to do e.g. **^1**, **^2**, etc. to Switch to Desktop (n), it's built-in to macOS in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control.  You just have to check them so the keyboard shortcuts are active.

Comment: Yes of course.  i knew that and then thought Which Space enabled that. the only thing Which Space does is put the space number in the menu bar.  i will delete my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.